# Rails doesn't seem to be looking for partial in the same directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on exercise 3 in Chapter 10 of Michael Hartl's *The Ruby on Rails Tutorial*.
I'm refactoring code in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb and moving it into the two partials:

1. app/view/static_pages/_signed_in.html.erb
2. app/view/static_pages/_non_signed_in.html.erb

and calling *render* on both files. For some reason I get this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error:
>   Missing partial static_pages/non_signed_in, application/non_signed_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.

However, when I move the two partials to the sibling directory app/view/static_pages/shared and tell *render* to look there (i.e. "render 'shared/signed_in'" and "render 'shared/non_signed_in'"), the error disappear. Thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you have omitted the '_' from the partial's filename? Or possibly had a file named _not_signed_in instead of _non_signed_in?

Comment: What does the partial invocation from you view look like?

Comment: Fred: my file names are _signed_in.html.erb and _non_signed_in.html.erb.

Comment: Zeantsoi: <% if signed_in? %> <%= render "signed_in" %>
<% else %>
 <%= render "non_signed_in" %>
<% end %>

Comment: Try this <%=render partial: 'static_pages/signed_in'%>